# inner join on index - unknown column

Tags: mysql, indexing, inner-join

```
SELECT T1_C1,...,T1_C100, T2_C1,T2_C2 FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 on T1.index_T1 = T2.index_T2
```

As above, I'm trying to inner join from two tables on the indexes I made using the code below

```
CREATE INDEX index_T1 on T1 (T1_PID)
CREATE INDEX index_T2 on T2 (T2_PID)
```

I keep getting unknown column 'T1.indexT1'. I get the same if I remove the table prefix. I'm struggling to find a working example of the correct syntax. Is there a special treatment that I need to apply first to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mention index by name explicitly ever.

Index name is only an identifier for you to maintain indexes (like to delete it). And mysql uses indexes automatically, based on which columns participate in query and which columns and how are covered by indexes.

So just specify column names:

```
INNER JOIN T2 on T1.t1_pid = T2.t2_pid
```

PS: for this particular query you most likely don't need index for `T1` table